# Extract and plot data from a file in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, extract

I have some data stored in a file (xyz.dat) in the following format:

```
1   0.997790664988225E+000   0.100177762164687E+001   0.100034262755073E+001        
2   0.997788473973293E+000   0.100177969047903E+001   0.100034273413754E+001        
3   0.997782981718032E+000   0.100178486093194E+001   0.100034301665219E+001
```

What I want to do is, for each row, store the first column as `x` and rest of the values as `y[1]`, `y[2]`, `y[3]`...so on. Later I want to plot the data stored in `y[n]` for each row separately. I am new to python and have tried using split() but did not have much success. I am either not able to separate out the first column or at the end of each row there is a trailing `'\n'`. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read and plot as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('xyz.dat', sep=' ', header=None, usecols=(1, 2, 3)).T
df.plot(lw=0.5)
plt.show()
```

This would give you output:

[image: matplotlib output]

Your 3 rows contain very similar data.

---

If the number of columns is unknown, you could just read it in normally and drop the first CSV column (actually first row after being transposed):

```
df = pd.read_csv('xyz.dat', sep=' ', header=None).T.drop(0)
df.plot(lw=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! What if the number of columns is unknown?

Comment: In that case, don't use `usecols`, and drop the first CSV column using `.drop(0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_fwf('file.dat')
plt.plot(df.iloc[:, 0], df.iloc[:,1])
plt.show()
```

You can go about plotting in the manner shown above. Hope this helps.